# pass associative array from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, associative

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass an array of strings from PHP to Javascript using $.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499757/how-to-pass-an-array-of-strings-from-php-to-javascript-using-ajax)

I want to pass a associative array from php code to javascript code. Please help me. how do I do this ? Is JSON helpful in this matter? If yes then please provide a simple code for help. Thank you.

From comment below:
HTML + PHP code

```
<td> 
    <input type="text" style="width:70;" name="<?php echo $quantity;?>" id="<?php echo $quantity;?>" onkeyup="check_valid_range('<?php echo $itemName;?>','<?php echo $quantity;?>',<?php echo json_encode($product_inventory);?>);">
</td> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function check_valid_range(product_field, quantity_field, inventory){ 
        var product = document.getElementById(product_field).value; 
        var quantity = document.getElementById(quantity_field).value; 
        var v = inventory[product]; 
        alert(v); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Done research much? This is actually a somewhat common task (however, converting to JSON is not technically enough, "</script>" appearing in the JSON is a counter-example. JSON "works" simply because it is a proper subset of Javascript Literal Notation.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This is not a terrible question.

Comment: Think its because its a Duplicate.

Comment: That a duplicate question exists is not a valid reason to downvote.  You downvote because a question is difficult to understand or poorly-worded, not because someone else asked the same thing already.

Comment: @cdhowie If you hover over the downvote button you will see that it says: "this question does not show any research effort". Given that there is almost 4k results in the linked search above and there is multiple duplicates, this clearly warrants a dv. There should be even more results on Google for that. This question does not deserve any upvotes.

Comment: What is the value of alert(v)?

Comment: function is not working. no output. I think this is because calling of the function is wrong. But I dont know what is wrong

Comment: @Gordon I have Google enough. I asked this question because I am passing the array using a function and the function is not working.

Comment: @Abhimanyu1310 - are there any errors in the console? One of your  `document.getElementById(...).value` might be returning null.

Comment: @pst this is wrong, JSON allows to escape the `/` character for the purpose of escaping `</script>`, and json_encode does it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217054/pass-associative-array-from-php-to-javascript/7217312#7217312

Comment: If I dont use json_encode($arrayname) then it works perfectly. But when I pass the array it doesn't. And no error on console.

Comment: Please post your JSON string from your array.

Answer (score 9):

JSON is perfect:

```
<?php

$mySweetJSONString = json_encode($myAssocPHPArray);

?>
<script>
    var iWantThePHPArrayHere = <?php echo $mySweetJSONString; ?>;
</script>
```

User [pst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst) brought up these concerns:

- `"array("</script>") -- darn, just broke this "perfect" approach."`
  It seems to work because (`</script>` => `<\/script>`):
   [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLasB/)
- `"What about ]]> which could occur in XHTML?"`
  The string is able to be transferred.
  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bp784/)

---

**Update:**

In regards to debugging the problem with the JS:
Are there any errors in the console? One of your `document.getElementById(...)` might be returning a null.  Therefore the member `value` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @cdhowie, I usually try to have complete code O_o

Comment: No problem, just trying to make the code clearer.  :)  +1 too, this is the right approach.

Comment: This is not very happy when "</script>" appears in the JSON. While JSON is a subset of JavaScript literals, not all JavaScript literals are valid in a <script> element (and I'm ignoring XHMTL entirely). I really wish there was a function designed *just to facilitate this particular use-case* with it's little caveats.

Comment: I am doing the same thing. json_encode function. But with a small difference, I am passing array of php to js by calling a function. And the function is not working. I just used alert() in the calling funcition to check if value is received. But nothing happened.

Comment: Why would '</script>' appear in the JSON?  I don't understand your comment

Comment: @Abhimanyu1310 - Please post your code, I cannot debug code I cannot see

Comment: `code`<script type="text/javascript">
 function check_valid_range(product_field, quantity_field, inventory)
 {
  var product = document.getElementById(product_field).value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById(quantity_field).value;
  var v = inventory[product];
  alert(v);
 }
 </script>


`code`
<input  type="text" style="width:70;" name="<?php echo $quantity;?>" id="<?php echo $quantity;?>" onkeyup="check_valid_range('<?php echo $itemName;?>','<?php echo  $quantity;?>',<?php echo  json_encode($product_inventory);?>);">

Comment: sorry I dont know how to post the code more clearly. New on Stackoverflow.

Comment: `code <script type="text/javascript"> function check_valid_range(product_field, quantity_field, inventory) { var product = document.getElementById(product_field).value; var quantity = document.getElementById(quantity_field).value; var v = inventory[product]; alert(v); } </script> `

Comment: post it in your question

Comment: This is perfectly safe, even if the string contains `</script>`. PHP's json_encode escapes the `/` for this purpose.

Comment: @arnaud576875 Corrected downvote. What about `]]>` which could occur in XHTML?

Comment: That may (assuming that the document is really parsed as XML) close the CDATA node, not the script element. That may cause a XML syntax error if the document is parsed as XML (nobody send an xml content-type).

Answer (score 0):

I always believed JSON were invented for this:

```
<script>
    var myArray = <?=json_encode($myArray)?>;
</script>
```

This will render like this:

```
<script>
    var myArray = {"key":"value","key2":"value2",...};
</script>
```

#### Safeness

This is perfectly safe for javascript, as JSON is a subset of the javascript syntax. This means that any JSON string can be treated as Javascript.

[PHP's `json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) is perfectly safe when embedding JSON in `<script>` tags too, because PHP escapes the `/` character:

```
json_encode('</script>');
=> "<\/script>"
```

So it's not possible to write `</script>`, which is the only way to escape a `<script>` tag. (Everything in a `<script>` tag is part of the script, it's not parsed as HTML.) JSON [allows to escape the `/`](http://www.json.org/) for this purpose.

So no JSON string can escape a `<script>` tag.