# how can I return array from php to javascript using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have this ajax code

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById('addIO').innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getRelatedConceptsAndRelations/3/TRUE",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

and I have a php array

`$cars=array("Saab","Volvo","BMW","Toyota");`

how can i send the array $cars to my javascript ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass an array of strings from PHP to Javascript using $.ajax()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499757/how-to-pass-an-array-of-strings-from-php-to-javascript-using-ajax)

Comment: Also see [how to parse json in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript).

Comment: i am trying to read it , thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### PHP

```
echo json_encode($cars);
```

### JavaScript

**Native**:

```
var foo = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

**With jQuery**:

```
var foo = $.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
//or
$.getJSON("url", function(data){
    //data is your array
});
```

---

### UPDATE

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
     //document.getElementById('addIO').innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
    var cars = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);  //cars will now be the array.
     //Do whatever you want here.
    $("#addIO").html(cars.join(", "));     //Join array with ", " then put it in addIO
}
```

If you want to use jQuery, put this in `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="link/to/the/file/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works, and if your browser does not support it, try [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Comment: do u mean that i have to do ur code instead of my fourth code in my function?

Comment: i don't know jQuery, so please would u tell me where should i put ur javascript line code in my function

Comment: i tried this on my function
document.getElementById('addIO').innerHTML=foo[0];
but it doesn't echo anythink

Comment: @William: This has nothing to do with jQuery. `xmlhttp.responseText` contains the response of the request as you already know. Put the code there where you have access to `xmlhttp.responseText`. If you are new to Ajax, you might want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: @WilliamKinaan jQuery is only used for parsing JSON if the browser does not support it.

Comment: thank you all
i am using google chrome
is my last two lines should still there ?

Comment: when i put the update section and after it i tried to alert("roma") , even alert doesn't work , :(

Comment: it wooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooorks
thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
i loooooooooooooooooove youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu:) :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [JSON](http://json.org):

```
echo json_encode($cars);
```

Comment: @Itay Moav - `JSON.parse()` in JavaScript.

Comment: thank you for ur answer
but how can i save the returned data on my javascript?

Comment: @Derek I am not the one who asked the question.